# Replacing value inside directive without replacing entire directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a template for my directive, which contains a scope variable called `content`:

```
<div class="directive-view">
    <span class="directive-header">My Directive</span>
    {{content}}
</div>
```

I have the following directive:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('myApp.myDirective', [])
        .directive("myDirective", myDirective);

    function myDirective($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
            },
            templateUrl:'../partials/directives/my-directive.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.content = "<span>Some HTML &mdash; some more HTML</span>";
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var compiledContent = $compile(scope.content)(scope);
                scope.content = compiledContent;
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

What I expect to see in place of `{{content}}` is:

```
Some HTML — some more HTML
```

What I see there instead is:

```
{"0":{"ng339":23},"length":1}
```

How do I set a scope string's value to some initial value, and then update it (as compiled HTML) from within the directive link, when the directive is compiled?

Comment: You want sort of placeholder until content is resolved and replaced?

Comment: One little correction, it should be `app.directive('myDirective')` instead of `app.directive('my-directive')`

Comment: I want to compile `{{content}}` once I am inside the `link` portion of the directive. I can't seem to figure out a way to replace just `{{content}}` and not everything.

Comment: Did you get the chance to try out my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working [plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/PUEYxNE3xwnWYsdgJJPs?p=preview)

First things first, change:

```
.directive('my-directive')
```

to

```
.directive('myDirective')
```

Also, from what I have gathered, you want html embedded in your directive template at compile time using a scope variable that resides in your directive. You don't need `$compile` for this.

For that, you need to use `ngBindHtml` as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="directive-view">
    <span class="directive-header">My Directive</span>
    ><div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(content)"></div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
function myDirective($compile, $sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        },
        template: '../partials/directives/my-directive.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.content = "<span>Some HTML &mdash; some more HTML</span>";
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {


            scope.trustAsHtml = function(val) {
              return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want some kind of placeholder text/html in place of `content` binding until it's resolved and applied. In this case you would better fix it in template:

```
<div class="directive-view">
    <span class="directive-header">My Directive</span>
    <span ng-bind-html="content">Some HTML &mdash; some more HTML</span>
</div>
```

<sub>And yea, `.directive("my-directive", myDirective);` should be `.directive("myDirective", myDirective);` but I guess this is just typo.</sub>

Comment: If I put any HTML into the new value for `content`, then this does not work. This: `scope.content = $compile("<strong>foo</strong>")(scope);` puts the string `[[object HTMLElement]]` where the old value of `content` used to be.

Comment: Why do you want to compile it? Just set new scope.content value.

Comment: If I set `scope.content = "<strong>foo</strong>"` then the string is not formatted as HTML. I see the literal string `<strong>foo</strong>` and not **foo**.

Comment: You need to use ng-bind-html directive. Check updated answer. And make sure you include ngSanitize module for this.